# Apollo GraphQL returns null when querying a SQL Server table

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have this table in the  SQL Server database: the table name is *small_customer*:

```
customerid| first_name | last_name | starting_date |
--------- | -----------| --------- | --------------|
```

this is code in *CustomerModel.js* in which I connect to the SQL Server database and Sequelize the types:

```
const CustomerModel= Conn.define('small_customer',{
    customerid: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    first_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    last_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    starting_date: {type:Sequelize.DATEONLY},
});
const Customer= Conn.models.small_customers;
export default Customer;
```

This is the *Query.js*  :

```
import { CustomerModel, CustomerType, CustomerArgs} from './models/customer';
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      customer : {
        type: CustomerType,
        args: CustomerArgs,
        resolve(root,args){
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           return resolve(Customer.find({ where: args }));
            }); } }}}});
```

I have defined *CustomerType.js*:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Customer',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      customerid: {type:GraphQLInt},
      first_name: {type: GraphQLString},
      last_name : {type: GraphQLString},
      starting_date: {type: GraphQLDate},
    }}});
```

When I write the query in order to select customer data based on the customerid and firstname, i have this error that

> it Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

here is the example of my query and the result in GraphiQL:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

means that Customer has `undefined` type and your are performing the `find` Operation on the `undefined` as `Customer.find({ where: args })`

Import `CustomerModel` in `Query.js`

```
import { Customer } from './models/CustomerModel';

// i haven't used babel so require, if only schema is defined in CustomerModel
// const Customer = require('./models/CustomerModel');

import { CustomerModel, CustomerType, CustomerArgs } from './models/customer';

export default new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            customer: {
                type: CustomerType,
                args: CustomerArgs,
                resolve(root, args) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        return resolve(Customer.find({ where: args }));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```